# JetBrains PyCharm is great, but I don't want to spend the $99

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm sure this question is a great candidate for being closed as not being strictly a programming question but here goes.
I started developing a simple toy website using Django. The IDE I decided to use was JetBrains's PyCharm. My trial period has no expired. Can you recommend another IDE that's comparable to PyCharm but doesn't cost the $99?
Or do you think PyCharm is worth the $99?
I'd like to eventually incorporate myself so i can expense these types of expenditures, but as of right now, I can't wait until I'm incorporated to start developing .
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: I'm running Fedora 13.

Comment: Take the pain and pay the $99. Your development time is worth more than that, if you account for finding a replacement and learning how to use it.

Comment: Couldn't agree with Randolph more. Jetbrains never charge without making sure that they are worth it so you will not find something comparable without paying anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I purchased PyCharm as I do not find Eclipse with PyDev to really deliver what I need.

Of course, your mileage may vary, but I found the ease of which I could use TextMate syntax highlighting schemes with PyCharm a very large plus. I am rather infatuated with Monokai as my default colour scheme and setting it up with PyCharm was so much less painful than having to try and get Eclipse to play nicely.

Also, the download/update is more manageable with PyCharm than it is or ever will be with Eclipse.

The developers at JetBrains are also very responsive with regard to feature requests and bug fixing.

All in all the positive sides of PyCharm were for me the reason to bite the bullet and spend the money. As a disclaimer I have to mention that I had been able to buy it at the 50% price which was available during beta testing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this for future reference.

First, if you are in dire straits - try contacting JetBrains and ask for a trial extension. Thats what I did when I started out with Pycharm and couldn't afford a license. They were super helpful.

Buying the license was the first thing I did when I actually could spare the money.

Pycharm is worth every penny and will help you work faster and better. JetBrains products are in my opinion second to none (perhaps Visual Studio) and cheap for what they offer.

The best part of Pycharm is their JavaScript editor which really beats anything I had laid my hands upon before. Editing Python is pretty unproblematic in any environment. But JS can be a bitch.

I cannot stress this enough, support the JetBrains team for the sheer awesomness they are unleashing upon the world.

Answer (score 2):

Try [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org) from Aptana. [Tutorial](http://www.leo-sa.com/?p=72) on setting it up on windows.

Comment: PyDev is a great eclipse extension and really makes Django a lot easier. Also get [Django Editor](http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/updates) for template syntax highlighting/checking